# Append column and default data into new Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append data from column and a default phrase at the same time into a Pandas DataFrame, `db` has many columns, not only id_sin & extra...

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
db = pd.DataFrame({'id_sin':['s123','s124','s125','s126'],
                   'extra':['abc','def','ghi','jkl'],
                   ...
})
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id_sin','phrase'])
df = df.append([db['id_sin'],['default phrase']*len(db)])
```

This is the expected result:

```
>>> df
  id_sin          phrase
0   s123  default phrase
1   s124  default phrase
2   s125  default phrase
3   s126  default phrase
```

But I am getting an error, please help... thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just `db['Phrase'] = 'default phrase'` ????

Comment: I need to take the column and append it with the default phrase... please help!

Comment: what first part? what errors?

Comment: My suggestion gives you exactly the output you need

Comment: It's not same DataFrame, I have one DataFrame that has the id_sin and I want to create a new DataFrame and append data to it.

Comment: I think you are right, I need map, please provide a code as I'm new to this.

Comment: Just to clarify, You have a DataFrame (`db`) with many columns and what you would like is to create another DataFrame with a subset of the original columns (in this case just `'id_sin'`) and another column called phrase which takes on a static value for all rows? If so, you want: `df = db[['id_sin']].assign(phrase='default phrase')`. Otherwise please try to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: It worked!!! Add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of existing DataFrame and then add new column to it.

```
import pandas as pd
db = pd.DataFrame({'id_sin':['s123','s124','s125','s126'],
               'extra':['abc','def','ghi','jkl'],
               ...
})

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id_sin'] = db[['id_sin']]
df['Phrase'] = 'Default Phrase'
```